# RMI serialization/marshal

Tags: java, serialization, rmi

I need some clarification on serialization in java. If i am serializing an object and i want to return that object over RMI do i just implement serializable on my object's custom class? I've seen objectoutputstream and objectinputstream but i don't know if i need to use those as i don't quite undersand their usage. My second question is how would i go about making an arraylist serializable? My third question is maybe related to my first question but how do i marshal an object before returning it? does serializing the object marshals it in the process?

Lets call the class in question Sentence:

```
public class Sentence implements Serializable  {

}
```

And then i would be creating an instance of that class and returning that object from some other class

Comment: just sign the class with `Serializable` marshalling and unmarshalling are JVM(low) level thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Yes: implementing Serializable makes your object serializable, unless it references an object that is not serializable. Object streams are used internally by RMI to send and receive objects. You don't need to use them if using RMI. If you want to send an object using sockets, or save it to a file, then you can use them.
2. ArrayList is already serializable. Look at its javadoc. You don't have to do anything.
3. You simply return the object from your RMI method, and RMI will serialize it for you. Serialization and marshalling are two words that basically mean the same thing. In the same way, if an RMI methods takes an argument, RMI will serialize the object passed as argument, send it to the RMI server, which will deserialize it and then call your actual method. It's all done for you by RMI.

Comment: It's all done for you by RMI. You get a reference to a remote object, you call it as if the object was not remote, and RMI does the job a serializing the arguments, send them to the server, deserialize them on the server, calling your method, serialize the return value, send it back to the client, and return it to the client that called the remote method.

Comment: yep got it, must have skipped some of your answer #3, ty!

Answer (score 1):

`Serializable` is what's called a *marker interface*; it just tells Java that your class has some ability without requiring you to implement any particular methods. Implementing it in your class tells the JVM that it's okay (meaningful) to take the fields of your Java object and convert them to a packaged form for use later or on another computer.

That's all you have to do *if* all of the fields in your class are `Serializable`. If you have fields that aren't `Serializable`, such as fields that hold network connections or native resources, you'll need to mark them `transient` (ignored by serialization) and take care of setting them back up when your class is deserialized by overriding `readObject` and/or `writeObject`.